# How to get same Vue components from page by some attribute

Tags: vue.js

I want to get from an Accordion vue component all others Accordion components on the page with the same props or data value.

I've tried a method `this.$parent.$children`, but it will not working if components are in different wrappers.

```
let state = this.active;
this.$parent.$children.forEach(value => {
    if (value.commonCssClass === this.cssClass)
        value.active = false;
    });
this.active = !state;
```

Comment: Post a portion of your code to illustrate what you want and what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

How about register components that you need in lifecycle methods?

in beforeMount register that component in global object
and beforeDestroy to un-register it

Comment: glad that it helps ) my first answer @ stackoverflow )

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve my problem.

```
beforeMount() {
    if(!window.VueAccordeons)
        window.VueAccordeons = {};
    if(!window.VueAccordeons[this.cssClass])
        window.VueAccordeons[this.cssClass] = [];
    window.VueAccordeons[this.cssClass].push(this);
},
beforeDestroy() {
   if(window.VueAccordeons)
       delete window.VueAccordeons;
},
```